# HTML Tooltip after selecting text in an <input> or in a <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

Ok, so basically what I need is that when I select some text in an `<input>` or in a `<textarea>`, a tooltip appears with two buttons, and then get the selected text in a Javascript variable.

The image below is an example of what I need:

[image]

```
var selectedText = "s is an in"
```

I'm using [Powertip](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/) for the tooltip and [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) for manipulating selections in `<input>` and `<textarea>`, the problem is that I can't manage to popup the tooltip and get the selected text in a JS variable **after** I select the text with the cursor.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE:

Thanks to Todd answer, I'm sharing what I was trying to achieve:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa83ro37/)

Comment: so, you have the plugins already working, right? I'm seeing a lot of answers that seem to miss the question asked. can you put YOUR work into a js fiddle or codepen, so we can get the RIGHT question answered, if we've not already. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
$('input, textarea').powerTip({ manual: true }); // have to prevent default plugin


$('input, textarea').on({
    'select': function() {
        var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
        $(this).powertip('show');
     },
     'blur': function() {
        $.powerTip.hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I've updated my question with the JSFiddle to let you know what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add mouse up event on selection of a text and can get the selected text, after that when you will show the selected text, you can also show the tool-tip with that.

Here is the [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/zL1tt20L/) for showing the text selection, you can update this and can also show the tool-tip where I have printed the selected text.

How to show tool-tip box:

**Step-1)** You need to get the top and left of the input field.

**Step-2)** Create a box using HTML and CSS.

**Step-3)** Set it's position to absolute and it's container to relative.

**Step-4)** Set it's top and left to that you have received in Step-1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Modal to create popup, create a Text Field Select Event & a Function to trigger open anchor.
Thats all you need.

here is a working example I have created:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Text Select Modal</title>

<style>
    .modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 300px;
    height:130px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #151414;

}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    window.open("#openModal","_self");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" onSelect="myFunction()">
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Button 1">
        <input type="button" value="Button 2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```